# Azure Key Vault: are Storage Account Keys still in preview?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

On the Key Vault Developers Guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-developers-guide) it is stated that the Storage Account Feature of Key Vault is still in preview. That message is dated July 10, 2017 (almost a year ago).

However, on the regular Key Vault documentation, there is no mention at all that this feature is still in preview. It is documented like any other property of the Key Vault, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-storage-keys .

Does anybody know whether this feature is actually still in preview? I can't find anything on the Key Vault blog about this, and the mail address azurekeyvault@microsoft.com directed me here for developer questions.